# Build debian package from git repo of my own software?

Tags: git, deb

I have my own trivial software project in git, and I'm wondering what the "standard" way is (if any) to build a DEB package. Ideally, I would want to use the tag-info (something like `git describe --tags`) to get the version info, and the changelog can be generated from the commits.

I figured git-buildpackage sounded like the right tool for the job, but having read the docs it seems like git-buildpackage is meant for a different and more complex use case. Looking at the git-buildpackage manual, it's not clear to me if my use case is really covered. It keeps mentioning existing software projects and upstream tarballs, and doesn't really mention building a software project.

Perhaps dpkg-buildpackage is more suitable, but using that I would have to keep track of versions and changelogs myself. Surely this has been solved many times over by developers all over the world?

Is there some other tool or method that is suitable to generate DEB packages from a git repo as described?

Comment: This doesn't seem to be a question about Git, or even about Debian packaging, but rather about how to use [a specific program included in Debian Linux](https://manpages.debian.org/testing/git-buildpackage/gbp-buildpackage.1.en.html). That would make it a question for superuser.com.

Comment: @torek I've rephrased a bit,  I don't want to limit the question to gbp because I suspect it may be the wrong solution. But I'm surprised I've not yet found a standard workflow to create a debian package from a version tag in a git repo, which I would think was a solved problem. Git-buildpackage sounds correct, but I haven't seen a description of this use case.